# horizon db clear

Tags: horizon, cli

I run the following commands:

```
horizon db clear
horizon db backfill
```

Error:

`2018/03/24 14:29:55 network-passphrase is blank: reingestion requires manually setting passphrase`

How to reingest the history?

Comment: This is definitely a valid question, but for those looking to help, it may be useful if you supplied some more information such as your setup, what you expected to happen, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your command looks fine, but you need to set some more variables. It says your "network-passphrase" is blank.

It wants this variable either via the envvar (Environment Variable) `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE`, or as a flag `--network-passphrase="XXX"` when running your horizon command.

For certain horizon commands, you may also need the 3 flags from [here](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md#configuring).